# Dense expects 2d but has got 3d in LSTM

Tags: keras, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, lstm-stateful

In my model

```
Xtrain shape : (62, 30, 100)
Ytrain shape : (62, 1, 100)
Xtest shape : (16, 30, 100)
Ytest shape : (16, 1, 100)
```

When I build my model,

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences= True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(units=100))

model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=5,batch_size=13)
```

when I try to fit it throws a error,

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (62, 1, 100)
```

I need to predict for the next 1 time stamp for all 100 features.
What are the changes needed to be done?

Answer (score 1):

The code posted doesn't seem to be the same that generated the error.

Print your `model.summary()`. You will see:

- LSTM 1: (None, 30, 100)
- LSTM 2: (None, 30, 100)
- Dense: (None, 30, 100)

You didn't use anything to reduce the number of time steps to 1. Your error message, according to this model should definitely be complaining about trying `(None, 30, 100)` vs `(62, 1, 100)`.

To eliminate the timesteps, you need `return_sequences=False` in the last LSTM, so your model becomes:

- (None, 30, 100)
- (None, 100)
- (None, 100)

This way, you can have `Ytrain.shape == (62,100)`

If you really really need that middle dimension == 1, just use `Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x, 1))` after the dense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the result of each LSTM step to be processed on its own (the most common use of placing a Dense layer after an LSTM or other RNNs), you need to wrap it, like so:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences= True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units=100)))
```

Each output will be served on its own to the Dense layer (of course, it would be the same layer - all weights will be shared between each 'instance' of it).